# Argument list too long error when executing aws-lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda that keeps failing in execution with the log output:

```
/var/task/bootstrap: line 30: /usr/bin/curl: Argument list too long
```

Line 30 refers to the bootstrap file when the Lambda attempts to send a response back to the client:

`# Send the response
curl -X POST "http://${AWS_LAMBDA_RUNTIME_API}/2018-06-01/runtime/invocation/$REQUEST_ID/response"  -d "$RESPONSE"`

Any insights on resolving this issue is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What's in $Response

Comment: I was able to resolve this by using this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174355